# Violacion de clave foranea PostgreSQL

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Buenas espero que estén muy bien, acudo a ustedes en busca de ayuda, verán, yo tengo varias tablas en mi BD pero las que pienso que me dan problemas son las tablas llamadas **"proyecto"** y **"triunfador"** , la tabla **"triunfador"** debe tener como llave foránea la llave primaria de **"proyecto"** y de hecho la tiene, pero al momento de querer insertar registros dentro de mi tabla llamada **"triunfador"** no puedo ya que me sale un error que no me deja continuar, espero que puedan ayudarme a comprender este mensaje y explicarme como solucionarlo, indagué en San Google pero no di con una respuesta certera, he aquí el señor error:

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23503]: Foreign key violation: 7 ERROR: insert or update on table "triunfador" violates foreign key constraint "triunfador_id_pro_fkey" DETAIL: Key (id_pro)=(6) is not present in table "proyecto". in /var/www/html/Modulos/Fermary/modelo/anadir-triunfador-modelo.php:151 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/Modulos/Fermary/modelo/anadir-triunfador-modelo.php(151): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /var/www/html/Modulos/Fermary/modelo/anadir-triunfador-modelo.php(131): IncluirTriunfador->IncluirTriunfador() #2 /var/www/html/Modulos/Fermary/controlador/anadir-triunfador-controlador.php(37): IncluirTriunfador->IncluirT() #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/Modulos/Fermary/modelo/anadir-triunfador-modelo.php on line 151
```

De esta manera se creó mi tabla "triunfador" se las colocaré tal cual me aparece en el pgadmin3:

```
 -- Table: public.triunfador

-- DROP TABLE public.triunfador;

CREATE TABLE public.triunfador
(
  id_triun integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('triunfador_id_triun_seq'::regclass),
  nombre_triun character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  apellido_triun character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  cedula_triun integer NOT NULL,
  trayecto_triun integer NOT NULL,
  seccion_triun character varying(6) NOT NULL,
  condicion_triun character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  id_pro integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('triunfador_id_pro_seq'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT triunfador_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_triun),
  CONSTRAINT triunfador_id_pro_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_pro)
      REFERENCES public.proyecto (id_pro) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT triunfador_cedula_triun_key UNIQUE (cedula_triun)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.triunfador
  OWNER TO framework;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.triunfador TO framework;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.triunfador TO public;
```

Y aquí está mi otra tabla llamada "proyecto"

```
  -- Table: public.proyecto

-- DROP TABLE public.proyecto;

CREATE TABLE public.proyecto
(
  id_pro integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('proyecto_id_pro_seq'::regclass),
  nombre_pro character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  trayecto_pro integer NOT NULL,
  anio_pro integer NOT NULL,
  id_asesor integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('proyecto_id_asesor_seq'::regclass),
  id_ald integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('proyecto_id_ald_seq'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT proyecto_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_pro),
  CONSTRAINT fkald FOREIGN KEY (id_ald)
      REFERENCES public.aldea (id_ald) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fkasesor FOREIGN KEY (id_asesor)
      REFERENCES public.asesor (id_asesor) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.proyecto
  OWNER TO framework;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.proyecto TO framework;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.proyecto TO public;

-- Index: public.fki_fkald

-- DROP INDEX public.fki_fkald;

CREATE INDEX fki_fkald
  ON public.proyecto
  USING btree
  (id_ald);

-- Index: public.fki_fkasesor

-- DROP INDEX public.fki_fkasesor;

CREATE INDEX fki_fkasesor
  ON public.proyecto
  USING btree
  (id_asesor);
```

> Si no es mucha molestia en dado caso que puedan hallar la solución me sería de gran ayuda que me expliquen detalladamente como solucionar esto para que en el futuro en dado caso que se me vuelva a presentar esta situación pueda salir de ella fácilmente, gracias de antemano mi gente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abundando en la respuesta de [@Pablo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/19227/pablo):

El problema radica en que al insertar el `id_pro` le das por defecto el valor de una secuencia:

```
id_pro integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('triunfador_id_pro_seq'::regclass)
```

Pero especificas que `id_pro` debe existir en la tabla proyecto

```
CONSTRAINT triunfador_id_pro_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_pro)
  REFERENCES public.proyecto (id_pro) MATCH SIMPLE
```

La secuencia `triunfador_id_pro_seq` es independiente de la secuencia `proyecto_id_pro_seq` en la tabla de proyectos. Perfectamente podrías tener el mismo `id_pro` para dos triunfadores (esto según tu definición de tabla... por sentido común el mismo proyecto debiese tener un solo triunfador, pero eso es cosa tuya).

Sería más lógico declarar `id_pro` simplemente como `INTEGER` sin secuencia, y asegurarte, en tu capa de negocios, de que el proyecto exista, y en caso contrario crearlo. 
Podrías hacer:

```
INSERT INTO proyecto (id_pro, nombre_pro, trayecto_pro, anio_pro, id_asesor, id_ald) 
VALUES (6, 'nombre', 'trayecto', 2018, 1, 1)
ON CONFLICT (id_pro) DO NOTHING;

INSERT INTO triunfador ...
```

Pero tienes otros 2 problemas muy similares al de tu pregunta

**Primero**, `id_ald` tiene por defecto el valor de una secuencia y a la vez una FK a `aldea.id_ald`.

```
id_ald integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('proyecto_id_ald_seq'::regclass)
...
CONSTRAINT fkald FOREIGN KEY (id_ald) REFERENCES public.aldea (id_ald) MATCH SIMPLE
```

De nuevo, la secuencia `proyecto_id_ald_seq` difícilmente estará sincronizada con la secuencia de la llave primaria de la tabla `aldea`. Si dos proyectos se relacionan con la última aldea insertada también tendrás un error de llave foránea.

**Segundo**, lo mismo ocurre con `id_asesor`

```
id_asesor integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('proyecto_id_asesor_seq'::regclass),
...
CONSTRAINT fkasesor FOREIGN KEY (id_asesor) REFERENCES public.asesor (id_asesor) MATCH SIMPLE
```

No tienes que asignarle una secuencia como valor por defecto. Tienes que usar tu capa de negocios para asegurarte de insertar en `proyecto` los valores de `id_asesor` y `id_aldea` que correspondan en la tabla referenciada.

Comment: ¡Excelente mi hermano! me has ayudado muchísimo, gracias por todo.

Answer (score 1):

Estás intentando insertar un registro en la tabla "triunfador" que hace referencia a un elemento que no existe en la tabla "proyecto".

Revisa el contenido de la tabla "proyecto".